# Subversion Path on Ubuntu Server

Tags: svn, ubuntu, find

Might be a dumb question.  But I installed SVN 1.4.6 via apt-get.  Everythings working dandy with no issues.  I want to backup all the SVN files so I figured to backup /svn which is where appache is setup to look for.

Anyhow.  I have a file called retroeventhandler.vbs.  When I run

```
sudo find / -name retroeventhandler.vbs
```

I get nothing back.  But I can browse the server at ip/svn/ and see all the files there.

Any ideas where these files should be?  Am I missing something.

**UPDATE based on squillman's post:**

ls -l /svn/repos/avqbsync/db/revs returns

```
total 35252
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data root         115 2009-09-01 14:42 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data root     9445835 2009-09-01 14:42 1
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data root        2490 2009-09-01 14:42 2
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data root         800 2009-09-01 14:42 3
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data    4779 2009-09-08 14:06 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 8914223 2009-09-08 14:45 5
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 8816246 2009-09-08 16:28 6
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data     651 2009-09-08 16:30 7
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data     862 2009-09-08 16:31 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 8818276 2009-09-08 16:35 9
```

My understanding is that each of these are revs or versions.  So if I backup this directory I presume I would later be able to restore the files?  Or no.  Sorry if this is a noob question, just a bit confusing.

**Another Update:**
Found this [link](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch05s03.html) which might give me a better solution:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subversion stores repository information inside a database of flat files.  If your repository lives in /svn, then that's where your committed files are.  It doesn't actually store the repository data in the same filestructure as you create on the client-side.  You won't actually see retroeventhandler.vbs at the filesystem level.

If you want to browse the repository use a [**subversion client**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Subversion_clients#Descriptions_of_Clients) (such as TortoiseSVN in Windows) or svnlook.

**In response to your edit:**
Have a look at [**this article**](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch05s03.html), toward the bottom it talks about backing up a repo using `svnadmin dump`.

Comment: I can browse the repos fine, my main thing is to be able to back them up.  please see my comment above.

Comment: ... and you should look into using `svnadmin dump` for your backup.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably be using `svnadmin dump` to do your backups.  I would strongly recommend reading through the [svn book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/)

Answer (score 1):

**squillman** is correct.  You won't find the files just sitting there, they are contained within the database. [Here](http://blog.markwshead.com/101/backing-up-subversion-automatically/) is a great perl script that performs a backup, copies it to another machine, tests the integrity of the backup, and emails you with the results.

Answer (score 1):

I just finished a shell script that does monthly full backups and nightly incrementals, all to an offsite server.  This is how it works:

The offsite server runs a nightly cron job.  On the first Sunday of every month, this script runs `ssh svnuser@myhost svnadmin dump /svnpath` and pipes the output to a file.  It then scans backwards from the end of the file and records the last revision number in a file.

On all other nights, the script runs, via ssh, 'svnlook youngest /svnpath' and compares the output to the last recorded (backed up) revision number.  If there have been new commits, it runs `svnadmin dump -q --deltas --incremental -r $LASTREV+1:HEAD /svnroot` and dumps the output to a file.

Then it runs some cleanup code to delete full dumps older than $N days and any incremental dumps older than the newest full.